# Pass Fragment + its state back to previous Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

In Activity A I have a portrait layout and a landscape layout. If a list item is tapped whilst in portrait a new FragmentActivity (Activity B) is started to display appropriate content. If in landscape a Fragment is shown on the right of the screen in Activity A to display the content.

My problem is:

If a user starts by holding the device in a portrait orientation and clicks a list item to open Activity B - and then turns the device to a landscape orientation, Activity B should be closed and the fragment shown on the right side of the screen in Activity A.

I am not sure how (or whether it is possible) to pass the Fragment in FragmentActivity B back to the fragment in Activity A. If I stop FragmentActivity B would the Fragment within it still be in the Fragment Manager for accessing in Activity A?

Is there a solution, or better way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> If I stop FragmentActivity B would the Fragment within it still be in the Fragment Manager for accessing in Activity A?

No, as each activity has its own `FragmentManager`.

> better way to achieve this?

Get rid of Activity B. Use fragment transactions and keep everything in Activity A.

Or, have Activity B detect that it is no longer needed in `onCreate()` (called after the configuration change) and have it `finish()` immediately.

Comment: Or, have Activity B detect that it is no longer needed in onCreate() (called after the configuration change) and have it finish() immediately.

I'm not sure how this would help me as I'd still need the Fragment in Activity B to appear within Activity A. It sounds like I'll have to do it all in Activity A which is a real pity.

Comment: @MichaelJ: "I'm not sure how this would help me as I'd still need the Fragment in Activity B to appear within Activity A" -- you would recreate the fragment in Activity A. Again, you cannot pass fragments between activities.

Comment: Recreating the Fragment is fine but what about state i.e. list scroll position?

Comment: @MichaelJ: That's where using multiple activities starts to break down.